# Approaches to prevent user from deleting home folder

Tags: home, xattr

I think prevent home folder from deleting is a very good idea. So I search possible approaches to do that. I that's what I’m find:

1. Use `chattr +i /home/user` - even root can't can add/delete/rename *user* folder and all direct children in *user* - good and bad.
2. Change owner of user directory to root and set sticky bit. Add file .keep and change his owner to root too:

   ```
   chown root:user /home/user
   chmod 1775 /home/user
   chown root /home/user/.keep
   ```

   root can delete */home/user*, user can't. But user can freely add/remove/rename files in his directory
3. Use `chattr +a /home/user` - same as first approach but user can add files.

I think `chattr +a` on home directory: `chattr +a /home` is the best way:

1. We can create new home folders for other users without pain.
2. We can freely edit files in */home/user*
3. We can't accidentally `sudo rm -rf /home/user`

Actually the question: what are the pitfalls of this approach?

Comment: Why all that complication in (2)? Just the existence of a root-owned `.keep` is enough, IMHO.

Comment: @muru ubuntu 14.04 ext4 just root-owned .keep does'n work

Comment: @muru Without a sticky bit, I could just delete the root-owned file, since I (*group*) have write permission over the directory.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith A sticky bit, granted, but root-ownership as well?

Comment: Have you considered corporal punishment? It might be worth a shot.

Comment: @muru The sticky bit grants permissions [to the parent directory owner as well as to the file owner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit). If *user* owns `/home/user`, he'll be able to delete `.keep`, even if it is owned by root under a sticky bit.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Ah, thanks. I was just checking that.

Comment: In (2) once `/home/user` is root:user,1775: why also `.keep`: what's the extra benefit? Also this /home/user setup _complicates_ ssh use of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` due sshd default option StrictModes, for me on centos-6.9. I thought only a rare few distro verify the group is a singleton of just user, no other members & then allow it?

Answer (score 7):

To remove a directory, you need *write* permission over its parent. Which means that as long as *user* can't write to `/home`, he won't be able to remove his own directory.

```
$ chown root:root /home
$ chmod 0755 /home

$ chown user:user /home/user
$ chmod 0750 /home/user
```

With these permissions, root is the only user who can manipulate directories immediately under `/home`. This setup is actually very common on Linux systems, since they are multiuser ; however, I have seen Ubuntu setups in which `/home` belonged to the first user (usually ID 1000). While Ubuntu's first user usually is a sudoer (meaning he could delete everything using `sudo`), I don't think it is a good practise to give `/home` to anyone but root.

When it comes to `chattr`, I believe this would be overkill. You are facing a permissions problem, there is no need for other file attributes.

Comment: They must have been custom setups. I have never seen a `/home` owned by anybody other than root on Ubuntu.

Comment: ```chattr +a``` runs on ```/home```, not on ```/home/user```

Comment: @IRus Indeed, my bad. Edited! Using the `a` flag is still overkill anyway.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith But ```a``` flag prevent from ```sudo rm -rf /home/user```. Why he is overkill? Because of performance problems or something else?

Comment: @IRus It is completely unecessary. A simple permission setup (as the one I gave in my answer) is enough to prevent `rm -rf /home/user` from *user*. If you're afraid you may do `rm -rf ...` as root, then think again before granting root privileges to such a command :) This is part of the reasons why you should use `sudo` instead of a root shell.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I'm trying to get rid of the human factor (you should now story about ```rm -rf /usr /lib/nvidia-current/xorg/xorg```), and keep files on my virtual machine, that shared with my friends (all in sudoers), in safe.

Comment: @IRus What I know is that I don't give root permissions to anyone, and I make sure that whoever has them won't be silly enough to remove a sensitive directory. If you want to remove the human factor, remove the users. The system will run just fine.

Comment: If you're trying to get rid of the possibility that people are silly, then there's only one solution: don't let people use the computer. If you don't limit physical access, they will be silly anyway—it's in our nature. :)